# Difference between arr.append(curr) and arr.append(curr[:])

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, deep-copy

Function to produce powerset gives the correct input.
However upon replacing append(curr[:]) with append(curr) gives a list of empty lists.
What is the reason?

```
def subsets(nums):
    def backtrack(first = 0, curr = []):
        # if the combination is done
        if len(curr) == k:  
            output.append(curr)
            return
        for i in range(first, n):
            # add nums[i] into the current combination
            curr.append(nums[i])
            # use next integers to complete the combination
            backtrack(i + 1, curr)
            # backtrack
            curr.pop()
    
    output = []
    n = len(nums)
    for k in range(n + 1):
        backtrack()
    return output
```

Comment: In addition to the specific question you've asked here, you might find it useful to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument - there's a chance that the `cur = []` that you're doing there is going to bite you.

Comment: While it is true that `curr[:]` will copy the list and that this is a recognized old habit, since 3.3 there is an explicit `.copy()` method that is preferred instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other answers have noted, `cur[:]` makes a copy of `cur`.  Without making a copy `output` ends up containing many copies of the same list - each of those lists are modified every time you call `cur.append` or `cur.pop`.

The lists end up *empty* because there is one call to `cur.pop` for every call of `cur.append`, which ensures that the "final" iteration of `cur` is going to be empty.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between `arr.append(curr)` and `arr.append(curr[:])` is that the first one copy the `curr` list address to `arr` and the second one copy the values of `curr` to `arr`.

Let's see the difference using examples.

First scenario:

```
curr = [5, 10, 15, 20]
arr = []
arr.append(curr)
print("Before update")
print("Curr: {}\nArr: {}".format(curr, arr))
curr[1] = 7
print("After update")
print("Curr: {}\nArr: {}".format(curr, arr))
```

Output:

```
Before update
Curr: [5, 10, 15, 20]
Arr: [[5, 10, 15, 20]]
After update
Curr: [5, 7, 15, 20]
Arr: [[5, 7, 15, 20]]
```

Second scenario:

```
curr = [5, 10, 15, 20]
arr = []
print("Before update")
arr.append(curr[:])
print("Curr: {}\nArr: {}".format(curr, arr))
curr[1] = 7
print("After update")
print("Curr: {}\nArr: {}".format(curr, arr))
```

Output:

```
Before update
Curr: [5, 10, 15, 20]
Arr: [[5, 10, 15, 20]]
After update
Curr: [5, 7, 15, 20]
Arr: [[5, 10, 15, 20]]
```

As you can see in first scenario both `curr` and `arr` is updated upon changing one index value of the `curr` list. Because appending the `curr` to `arr` holds the same memory address.

In second scenario only `curr` is updated upon changing one index value of the `curr` list. Because appending `[:]` to `arr` copies the contents to `curr` list to `arr` list.

According to said above(theory), the reason why you get an `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]` when you run the code changing `curr` for `curr[:]` is because in the last line `curr.pop()` in **backtrack** function you're removing the last elements one by one so you're taking off the elements from the list which is located at same space memory all the time and not from a copy list values of it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `arr.append(curr[:])` means append a **COPY** of `curr` while `arr.append(curr)` append `curr` itself to the array `arr`, meaning when you make any change to `curr`, it's value in `arr` will also change correspondingly

You can read more about array copy here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/list-changes-unexpectedly-after-assignment-how-do-i-clone-or-copy-it-to-prevent)